# Using single quotes within a string in EL

Tags: jsf

I need to write this string on JSF code :

```
rendered="#{person.value.equals('it's him')}"
```

My problem is with the `'` character.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: What is the error? Try escaping it first *\\* (my escape character, escaped)

Comment: `rendered="#{person.value.equals("it's him")}"`. Better use `rendered="#{person.value eq "it's him"}"` instead.

Comment: Then you're closing the string before 'it' and open after him...

Comment: thank's @Tiny, your code works too :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case the quote is inside the variable: oncomplete="setTimeout(\"cargarpaneledicion('#{emp.cif}','#{emp.cifActual}','#{emp.nombre}')\",600);". If the emp.nombre variable comes with quotes, it does not work... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<h:outputText value="My text with \'single quotes\' and \"double quotes\"" />
```

So:

```
rendered="#{person.value.equals('it\'s him')}"
```

Look at this:

```
<af:outputText inlineStyle="font-weight:bold;" value="#{viewControllerBundle.BEAN_ONLINE_VARIABLE_PASS_1}" id="ot22p_" rendered="#{empty pageFlowScope.sensor.payed and pageFlowScope.sensor.down eq 'false'}"/>
```